# How to loop through model files and initialize all of them?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose with MongoDb and I'm having trouble figuring out the Javascript code to run all my Mongoose models (one model in each file inside a directory) and initialize all of them.

Basically my file structure is like this:

```
models
-- User.js
-- Discussion.js
-- Node.js
-- etc.js
index.js
```

I need an initialize function inside index.js that will run each of the functions in the models. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Were you thinking about something like this? This will `include` all the files inside models and then run the module.exports function for each of them. This will essentially initialize all your models.

```
(index.js)    
exports.initialize = function() {
  require("fs").readdirSync(__dirname + "/models").forEach(function(file) {
    require('./models/' + file)();
  });
};
```

Comment: So this method should be inside my index.js file?

Comment: Yes, put this inside your index.js file and call it from elsewhere like require('index.js').initialize()